# Sequelize query element in array within a hash in JSONB

Tags: sequelize.js, jsonb

I have a model with a JSONB column

```
const Facility = sequelize.define('Facility', {
  name: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
  criteria: { type: DataTypes.JSONB }
}
```

I have objects that look like the following

```
facility1 = { name: "A", criteria: { unit_id: ['001', '002'], stuff: '1234' } }
facility2 = { name: "B", criteria: { unit_id: ['002'], stuff: '7845' } }
facility3 = { name: "C", criteria: { unit_id: ['001', '003'], stuff: '0009' } }
```

How do I query the unit_id in Sequelize? For example, I want to search for a facility that has unit_id `003`. I've searched for the proper syntax and I can't find it. I've tried something like the following but it doesn't work

```
Facility.findAll({
  where: {
    criteria: {
      unit_id: {
        [Op.contains]: '003'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this syntax.

```
Facility.findAll({
  where: {
    criteria: {
      [Op.contains]: {
        unit_id: ['002']
      }
    }
  }
});
```

`Op.contains` operator produces the `@>` operator in Postgres. According to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html, this operator is for

> Does the left JSON value contain the right JSON path/value entries at the top level?

Note that here it says "at the top level", so you want to add `Op.contains` at top level (table's column name) and wrap the JSON key inside of `Op.contains`.

Comment: That works partially! But if I have two facilities that contains `002` as shown in my question, only `facility2` would be returned. I would need it to return `facility1` as well

Comment: interesting. I got both returned. could you show the result when you do `where: { name: { [Op.in]: ['A', 'B'] }}`?

Comment: I'm so sorry! I read my results wrong (:facepalm:) I got both results! Thank you so much! And thanks for the explanation! It's really helpful

Comment: it's all good. glad you got a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing an array in the comparison:

```
Facility.findAll({
  where: {
    criteria: {
      unit_id: {
        [Op.contains]: ['003'], // ==> check here
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but that doesn't work